# Applescript to output "unread" mail (y/n) to serial port -- won't compile

Tags: email, serialization, serial-port, arduino, applescript

To start, I'm fairly new to Applescript. At the expense of buying an ethernet shield for my Arduino, I decided to dedicate a serial port to it (over usb).

This way, if I write an Applescript to check my mail and output an "N" for no new mail or an "M" for new mail to the serial port that it is connected to, it will respond accordingly. (More actions to be added later).

Anyway, I have been writing my script, and found another that seems to do what I want...

```
set use_port to "/dev/cu.usbmodemfa131"

if (get serialport list) contains use_port then

    set onMode to true
    set myPort to serialport open use_port bps rate 9600 data bits 8 parity 0 stop bits 1 handshake 0

    if myPort ≠ -1 then -- check the port opened correctly

        repeat while onMode is true

            tell application "Mail"
                set x to unread count of inbox
                check for new mail
                delay 600
                set y to unread count of inbox
            end tell

            if x = y then
                serialport write "N" to myPort
            else
                serialport write "M" to myPort
            end if

            -- add some logic here to determine whether to loop again, e.g.

            if foo = bar then set onMode to false

         end repeat

         serialport close myPort

    end if

end if
```

The issue, though, is that this does not compile. As I'm not familiar with Applescript enough to debug this myself, I'm asking for help.

(Note: I have a fully functional Arduino sketch that responds to M, N, and a few other commands over serial. I would just like to automate the sending of these commands, without having a "tell" (no apps open, just communication over serial). Any help would be appreciated!)

//New adjusted code follows

```
global myPort



on run

set use_port to "/dev/tty.usbmodem1d11"

if (get serialport list) contains use_port then

    set myPort to serialport open use_port bps rate 9600 data bits 8 parity 0 stop bits 1 handshake 0

    if myPort = -1 then -- check the port opened correctly

display alert "Ooops, unable to open the serial port " & use_port

tell me to quit

end if

else

    display alert "Oops. Serial port not found"

    tell me to quit

end if

end run





on idle

tell application "Mail"

    set x to unread count of inbox

end tell



if x > 0 then

    set mailStatus to "a"

else

    set mailStatus to "b"

end if

serialport write mailStatus to myPort



return 3 -- check again in 3 seconds

end idle





on quit

try

    serialport close myPort

end try

continue quit

end quit
```

Comment: It appears you are using the SerialPortX scripting addition (http://alteredhorizons.capnix.com/MacSoft.html) Have you installed into ~/Library/ScriptingAdditions/ ? If not this could be causing a failure to compile. Other wise let us know in your answer the error message you get when the compile fails.

Comment: This helped - I didn't have it installed, so I wrote the file to the directory. My issue, though (and sorry for not being clearer), is that I get  "Syntax Error: Expected “,” but found class name." And I'm not sure I see the syntax error.

Comment: Do the any of the examples provided with SerialPortX compile and run? This script is compiling and running fine for me (though i don't have that serial port or an arduino) Are you on Mavericks? Lots of little things seem to be broken on it at the moment.

Comment: All of the examples both compile and run correctly. I'm not on Mavericks, I've got an older Macbook that doesn't support above Lion, and I ended up downgrading back to Snow Leopard. So currently I'm running 10.6.8

Comment: Now, I've managed to get it compiled. I reinstalled the SerialPortX addons. However, it doesn't actually complete the action. It seems to just run, and quit.

Comment: I ended up separating the open/close serial ports from the actual commands... I'll update the code above to reflect my final code. Thanks for the help!